# How to put container div under menu using CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem, how can i make container div to be under menu, when i put container background it go beside a header and menu... Could someone help me to fix my problem?
My HTML and CSS bellow...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Рено Клуб Македонија - Добредојдовте</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="web">
    <div id="header">
        <div class="logo">
          <a href="#"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo"/></a>
        </div> <!-- logo end -->

            <div class="menu">
              <ul>
                  <li class="active"><a href="#" style="color:#ecd302">Почетна</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Форум</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Клуб</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Членство</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Галерија</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Огласник</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Контакт</a></li>
              </ul> <!-- main menu end -->
            </div> 
    </div> <!-- header end -->  
     <div class="container">

        <p id="petrol">Превземено од Макпетрол *цените се изразени во денари / литар </p>

     </div>
</div><!-- web end -->
```

```
@charset "utf-8";

body {
margin:0;
padding:0; 
width:960px; 
background:#e2e2e2; 
}

a {
text-decoration:none;
color:#ffffff;
text-shadow:1px 1px #000000;
}

a:hover {
text-decoration:none;
color:#a6a5a5;
}

a:active {
text-decoration:none;
color:#ecd302;
}

.web {
width:960px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}

#header {
 background-repeat:no-repeat; 
 display:block; 
 margin:auto; 
 padding:0px; 
 height:110px; 
 background:#ecd302;  
 position:absolute;
 top:0; 
 left:0; 
 right:0; 
}

.logo { 
background-repeat:no-repeat; 
width:305px;
height:85px; 
float:left; 
margin:10px 0 0 202px;
}

.menu {
background:#4b4b4b;
text-transform:uppercase;
word-spacing:32px;
font-size:20px;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-weight:bold;
text-decoration:none;
text-align:center;
border-bottom:1px solid #000;
border-top: 1px solid #000;
display:block;
position:absolute;
top:105px;
left:0;
right:0;
}

ul {

}


li {
display:inline;
}

.container {
background:#929191;
left:0px;
right:0px;
text-align:right;
width: 960px;
font-size:12px;

}
```

If my question is not understood please contact me... i will give more information.

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot of what you currently see with a more descriptive explanation of what you want

Comment: Yes sure, that is screenshot from index.html http://prntscr.com/6qxsre  In the HTML and CSS code i have <p id="petrol"> and <div id="container"> but i can't see it when i open index.html file

Comment: batko napravi jedan jsfiddle sine :D

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1dwsgcdd/  link :)

Comment: Quick fix - add margin-top ~ 200px to container, but... try to change header and menu positioning, from absolute to relative... Absolute positioning make problems, in this case - container div starts at the top of the page/.web div.... " In contrast, an element that is positioned absolutely is taken out of the flow and thus takes up no space when placing other elements" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: Add for exemple margin-top:190px; to container class.
I don't understand why you have used position absolute ?

Comment: I fix it... https://jsfiddle.net/azq50bsd/4/embedded/result/ but now i have problem with weight of header and menu, they are not full page weight... they are also 960px :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note, that using `position: absolute` stops an element from taking up any space, which is why other elements come to that position. The result is multiple elements being at the same place, which is what you mostly don't want. So only use `position: absolute`, when really necessary.

I removed `position: absolute` from `#header` and `.menu`. Now you also don't need `top`, `left` and `right` anymore.
You also don't need to define the `width` of the `body`, since it is already defined for `.web`. Additionally, I removed some styles from `.logo` and `#header` to get the result shown in the screenshot.

Updated Code:
http://jsfiddle.net/azq50bsd/5/

```
body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
background:#e2e2e2; 
}

a {
text-decoration:none;
color:#ffffff;
text-shadow:1px 1px #000000;
}

a:hover {
text-decoration:none;
color:#a6a5a5;
}

a:active {
text-decoration:none;
color:#ecd302;
}

.web {
width:960px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}

#header {
 background:#ecd302;
}

.logo { 
background-repeat:no-repeat; 
width:305px;
height:85px; 
margin:10px;
}

.menu {
background:#4b4b4b;
text-transform:uppercase;
word-spacing:32px;
font-size:20px;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-weight:bold;
text-decoration:none;
text-align:center;
border-bottom:1px solid #000;
border-top: 1px solid #000;
display:block;
}

ul {

}


li {
display:inline;
}

.container {
background:#929191;
left:0px;
right:0px;
text-align:right;
width: 960px;
font-size:12px;
}
```

Comment: That is my design, which i want to make in HTML and CSS so how can i make now header and menu like this... http://prntscr.com/6qy6x8

Comment: Yes i have it, but now there is another problem... i cant make header and menu width full web window, they are fixed on 960px...

Comment: Yes, because `.web` and `.container` are set to `width: 960px`. Remove that and you'll be fine: http://jsfiddle.net/azq50bsd/6/

Comment: Well, i need container 960px and logo to be inside centered 960px of full weight header... i send you e-mail... if you have time check it also :)